# Confusing QNEAT3 Exception: Unknown

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

When I try to run QNEAT3's "OD Matrix as Lines/CSV" function, I am getting a very strange error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/dicki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\OdMatrixFromPointsAsLines.py", line 207, in processAlgorithm
net = Qneat3Network(network, points, strategy, directionFieldName, forwardValue, backwardValue, bothValue, defaultDirection, analysisCrs, speedFieldName, defaultSpeed, tolerance, feedback)
File "C:/Users/dicki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 130, in __init__
self.list_tiedPoints = self.director.makeGraph(self.builder, self.list_input_points, self.feedback)
Exception: unknown

Execution failed after 53.70 seconds
```

Any thoughts? I'm at a loss - I've posted this in a few other places as well.

Comment: Which QGIS version is that? What does your data look like?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the latest version of QGIS 3 (have replicated the error on multiple systems) - my data is a large country-size OSM roads file. I've tried this with a few diff formats - spatialite, .shp, etc. I got a response from the creator who said "The part of the API that reports the error belongs to the QGIS internals and is not controlled by QNEAT3."